# Spring Controller's method called at startup when deploying locally to Tomcat a wep app under root(/) Context

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Well i have a very simple Spring MVC application , in which i have configured the dispatcher servlet to accept requests under the / pattern as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

I also have a simple Controller which accepts all requests under /*:

```
    @RequestMapping("/*")
    public ModelAndView index(HttpSession session) {
        System.out.println(session.getId());
        // do Smth heavy
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
```

Now i want to Deploy my web app in a Tomcat and put the web context root as / , so that when hitting localhost:8080 my index page would popup.
This is indeed working properly , but the problem is that during startup the method is getting called and spring logs the same but there is not any browser or something else to request that page.

In order to change the context path for the web app from Eclipse i am using the context descriptor in the modules tab.

[image: Modules Tab]

```
DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/]
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Looking up handler method for path /
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:227 - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.controller.MainController.index()]
DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mainController'
DEBUG DispatcherServlet:912 - Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
```

What i tried :

i) The Same war on a Wildfly by adding the below jboss-web.xml and it worked properly , without calling the /* path at startup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

ii) Also the same war on both Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8 , deployed with the name ROOT.war and again it worked properly without calling the index() method.

Maybe the eclipse's plugin is causing the issue because if i change the path to any other value , the method does not get called  , or have i missed something up ?

Sorry for the long title , couldn't find a more descriptive one.

**UPDATE** after Peter Rader proposal

Controller :

```
    @RequestMapping("/*")
    public ModelAndView index(HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest req) 
    {
        System.out.println(session.getId());
        System.out.println(req.getHeader("user-agent"));
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
```

Server Logs :

```
INFO: Server startup in 14690 ms
2016-08-17 18:25:53 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/]
2016-08-17 18:25:53 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Looking up handler method for path /
2016-08-17 18:25:53 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:227 - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.controller.MainController.index(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2016-08-17 18:25:53 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mainController'
2016-08-17 18:25:53 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG DispatcherServlet:912 - Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
735E606472EA914D4099265BD47474FA
Java/1.8.0_20
2016-08-17 18:25:56 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:1525 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'index'
2016-08-17 18:25:56 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1206 - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'index'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2016-08-17 18:25:56 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG JstlView:236 - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'index'
```

Comment: Deploying via command-line shows the same problem?

Comment: `System.out.println` should give some output but the log you post does not contains such an output. Why do you think the method is called?

Comment: @serg.nechaev nope , if i deploy it as ROOT.war and manually start the tomcat , everything is ok.

Comment: @PeterRader , well actually you are right ,  between the logs it prints the `Session ID` , but i posted only the Spring servlet's logs. Those logs are getting printed immediately after server's start up. Doesnt look strange ?

Comment: @AntJavaDev Ah, ok. Could you print the agent to the console please? Just use `(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest req)` instead of `(HttpSession session)` and add the line `System.out.println(req.getHeader("user-agent"));`.

Comment: @PeterRader , wow very nice thought , i have updated my question , it prints Java/1.8.0_20 which is the latest version i have installed and also the version which eclipse is using. So maybe is eclipse hitting the root (/) by some bad configuration to enable the web browser or smth like that ?

Comment: or i have a virus installed which is using the latest java version and hitting all http ports under localhost:## ?????!!?? could it be the antivirus or smth? Note i run it on a Windows 7 machine. havent tested on a linux one yet

Comment: @AntJavaDev Oh this could be the answer. I remember integrations where eclipse noticed a succeeded webcontainer start and open a new webbrowser-view inside eclipse. This might be your phantom-request. "A lost request ant-java has. How embarrassing...."

Comment: @PeterRader , yep i remember the same think , which was opening the internal eclipse browser. But still i cannot find any property to configure this setting and i cannot understand why i dont get the same behaviour when deploying to JBOSS and when deploying the ROOT.war manually to Tomcat

Comment: @PeterRader ok the problem might be with my eclipse version or with my Tomcat Connector plugin , i will try this afternoon to recheck with another version of eclipse and ill tell you if i still have the same issue.

Comment: @PeterRader , no change , i still get the same behavior , i changed both eclipse and java version.  Also i replicated the issue by going to eclipse right click on the Web Project > Settings > set the Context Root as "/" , instead of changing the Tomcat's module config. Note that when i am trying to do the same on JBOSS , without the jboss-web.xml , but simple by changing the context root of the web app , the app wont be deployed under the context root i have defined , but instead Jboss will use the web app's Name as the context root......